# How to prevent duplication of of an object by array.reduce function

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
    range: [number, number] = [135, 145]

    update(property: string, path: string, range: [number, number]) {   
            if (path.split('|').length === 2) {
                const steps = path.split('|')
                
                const addressSteps = steps.slice(0, -1)

                const lastStep = addressSteps[addressSteps.length - 1]
            
                const reducer = (accu, step) => accu[step]

                // We get to the branch you need to update
                const stateBranch = addressSteps.reduce(reducer, state)

                stateBranch[lastStep] = {
                    ...stateBranch[lastStep],
                    [property]: range,
                }

        }),
    )
}
```

Invoking the fuction...

```
update(bHbMaleMass, 'haematology|cbc', [135, 145])
```

...update the state as shown in the screen capture

[image]

Note the following:

1. the haematology node is INCORRECTLY duplicated in the cbc node with the correct updated data.

What I am trying to accomplish is to update the cbc node ONLY - there should be no duplicate of the haematology or cbc nodes.

Thanks for the help

NB previously posted at [Looking for a better way to structure code [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464414/looking-for-a-better-way-to-structure-code) which was closed. The question relates to one of the solutions offered in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
const lastStep = addressSteps[addressSteps.length - 1]
```

For

```
const lastStep = steps.slice(1,2)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution does remove the duplicate 'haematology' but introduces another issue. Look at the bHbMaleMass node in the screenshot - your solution replaces everything with the range - only the 0-index of bHbMaleMass should be replaced. Maybe a little more tweaking. I do appreciate the effort.